# Upload CSV format files to GCS as a Dataflow work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Upload the file to Google Cloud Storage.

Dataflow is being pre-processed by reading batch data.

The workload is read from Google Cloud Storage (GCS) to process Dataflow and upload it back to GCS.

But after processing the data, I checked the GCS.

```
 #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import apache_beam as beam
import csv
import json
import os
import re
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json

def preprocessing(fields):
    fields = fields.split(",")
    header = "label"
    for i in range(0, 784):
        header += (",pixel" + str(i))
    label_list_str = "["
    label_list = []
    for i in range(0,10) :
        if fields[0] == str(i) :
            label_list_str+=str(i)
        else :
            label_list_str+=("0")
        if i!=9 :
            label_list_str+=","
    label_list_str+="],"
    for i in range(1,len(fields)) :
        label_list_str+=fields[i]
        if i!=len(fields)-1:
            label_list_str+=","
    yield label_list_str


def run(project, bucket, dataset) :
        argv = [
            "--project={0}".format(project),
            "--job_name=kaggle-dataflow",
            "--save_main_session",
            "--region=asia-northeast1",
            "--staging_location=gs://{0}/kaggle-bucket-v1/".format(bucket),
            "--temp_location=gs://{0}/kaggle-bucket-v1/".format(bucket),
            "--max_num_workers=8",
            "--worker_region=asia-northeast3",
            "--worker_disk_type=compute.googleapis.com/projects//zones//diskTypes/pd-ssd",
            "--autoscaling_algorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED",
            "--runner=DataflowRunner",
            "--worker_region=asia-northeast3"
        ]

        result_output = 'gs://kaggle-bucket-v1/result/result.csv'
        filename = "gs://{}/train.csv".format(bucket)
        pipeline = beam.Pipeline(argv=argv)
        ptransform = (pipeline
                      | "Read from GCS" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(filename)
                      | "Kaggle data pre-processing" >> beam.FlatMap(preprocessing)
                      )
   
  
    (ptransform
    | "events:out" >> beam.io.WriteToText(
            result_output
        )
     )
    
    pipeline.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run pipeline on the cloud")
    parser.add_argument("--project", dest="project", help="Unique project ID", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--bucket", dest="bucket", help="Bucket where your data were ingested", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--dataset", dest="dataset", help="BigQuery dataset")

    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    print("Correcting timestamps and writing to BigQuery dataset {}".format(args["dataset"]))

    run(project=args["project"], bucket=args["bucket"], dataset=args["dataset"])
```

I am trying to do now is to upload a file containing a header to GCS and add data by working with the name of the file. However, it doesn't work well.

How can I include the header in the CSV file?

Comment: Do you want to name dynamically the file according to the data in the header?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, that's right.

I want to put the value of the header before PTransform after receiving data from Dataflow.

Comment: WriteToText  transform does not support specifying a dynamic header but you can provide a static header that will be included in all files written: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py#L602

Comment: @chamikara I think this method includes the header after creating the file, is it correct that I understand?

Comment: @꽥꽥꽥, have you looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917452)?

Comment: @Nick_Kh Oh, that's a great way.

Comment: This method will add a header to the beginning of every file created when writing. Method suggested by Daniel (other thread) will work if your data is small enough to fit in a single string in memory but probably will not work for a large dataset.

Comment: @꽥꽥꽥, Have you considered any solution across the proposed methods?

Comment: @Nick_Kh I don't have any idea. 
you metioned side-input method is a good way. but, each parallel process has header on the top recursively.

Comment: You can consider also writing a [custom source/sink](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io) particularly handling CSV files with adding headers processing, look at [example](https://github.com/pabloem/beam_utils/blob/master/beam_utils/sources.py). Is it sounds reasonable for you?

Comment: @Nick_Kh reply was late.
Does your meaning mean that I should create and write a CSV file instead of creating a CSV file through Dataflow processing?